# Apache Tomcat error: 404 page not found while the other jsp runs properly

Tags: javascript, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat, web

When I run sasas.html it gives 404 error while the other NewFile.jsp runs properly. I have tried may time by restarting server

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can run your `html` code as `JSP` page..
Rename the extension of your html page change `sasas.html` to `sasas.jsp`..

And add this directive to the top of your page :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

before : `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Thanks , I did the same ...its working but why is it happning..??